# Listen to error in Service Provider in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been using Laravel 5 for some time now and I'm creating my own logging layer for my application.

Since I want to log my failed queries I decided to create a Service Provider for this.

In the Service Provider I got this code:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->error(function (QueryException $ex) {
        dd('test');
    });
}
```

This should work, but it doesn't. I get the following error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::error()`

Somebody knows whats changed here. Cause I can't find the `error` method in the Application or Container class. Haven't found anything on the forums/github repo yet.

Comment: The error method is definitely still there, you can see it in their repo (https://github.com/illuminate/foundation/blob/master/Application.php). You must be doing something else wrong, try doing `dd($this->app)` to see what the object is.

Comment: @fire Its a `Application` instance. See: http://i.imgur.com/SyWN4bw.png. Weird that the error says there is no `error` method...

Comment: @fire That's the wrong repo. This is the right one: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php

Comment: @lukasgeiter then I was right. Any clue where the error method has moved to? Or it's renamed to something else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5 catching errors works differently. [Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/any-questions-about-upgrading-to-laravel-5?page=2)

You do it inside `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` by editing the `render()` method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e))
    {
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }

    else if ($e instanceof QueryException)
    {
        dd('test');
    }

    else
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

**Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#handling-errors**